# Public transportation cost and schedule in Maldives

Tags: public-transport, maldives

I have read that public transportation schedule can be found at this site: https://www.mtcc.com.mv/ but do not see any actual schedule there.

Also I can see some schedule here https://www.atolltransfer.com/ferry-routes-c17sd but I can't understand if this is actual schedule applied for 2019-2020 or is it obsolete

I have read some two blog entries contradicting each other saying the airport domestic flights are cheaper or more expensive than speed boats.

What is the current price of public transportation? Where can I read it?
If a ferry doesn't come, what are the options for a traveller in order not to miss the return flight to home country?

Do speed boats always come? Are there different schedule for speedboats or is it the same as for ferries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From all the resources I could find,
this one 
https://www.atolltransfer.com/ferry-routes-c17sd was updated 01 September 2018,

this one https://www.mtcc.com.mv/content/comprehensive-transport-network also was updated either 16th June 2018 or 01 September 2018.

There is some additional site which provides speed boats from Maafushi to Male and back
https://icomtours.com/

There is a service which search connections between islands against government ferry, private ferry and scheduled speed boats http://wildmaldives.com/en/ferry-schedule but it doesn't seem to work against distant islands